# making a drop-down list in Swift 3

Tags: swift

I'm trying to make drop-down list where picker view is not visible until user clicks on textfield.  Then picker view disappears after user makes selection from pickerView.  Currently, the picker View does not show up at all when I click on textfield.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource,     UIPickerViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var textBox: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!

    var choices = ["SortBy:", "Date(ascending)", "Date(descending)","Calories Burned(descending)","Duration(descending)"]

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        return choices[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return choices.count
    }

    fun pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int,   inComponent component: Int) {
        self.textBox.text = self.choices[row]
        self.pickerView.isHidden = true

        print("hello")
    }

    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(TextField:  UITextField){
        if TextField == self.textBox {
            self.pickerView.isHidden = false
            TextField.endEditing(true)
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.pickerView.isHidden = true
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

Comment: Not a direct answer, but you might want to take a look at https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0 - I've just customized one of their pickers to do what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.pickerView.isHidden = true
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.textBox.delegate = self
        self.pickerView.delegate = self 
    }
```